# no_results not working when moved to snippet

Tags: switchee, snippets, no-results

I have moved embed code to be a snippet. After that move no_results stopped to work (part of the code below)

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" category="{segment_2_category_id}" orderby="title" sort="asc" limit="8" paginate="bottom" dynamic="no"}

            {if no_results}
                    <div class=""><p>No entries yet.</p></div>
                {/if}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Any clue why it has stopped?

Comment: Is this code inside switchee?

Comment: 1. {if no_results} {/if} stop working or it is show all entryes like is no category="{segment_2_category_id}"?
2. needs to see what is around you snippet - possible some add-on has *no_results* tag also and execute before channel tag.

Comment: @RobsonSobral Correct - it is inside switchee. So I need to go back to embeds instead of snippets?

Comment: @MaxLazar #1 - Is stop working (blank div) #2 - snippets were used inside switchee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is issue related to switchee (thanks Robson Sobral for pointing me to that).

The {if no_results} behaviour is ‘owned’ by the outer wrapping tag not the inner tag. This is an EE bug/feature and not unique to Switchee.

Because of this, Switchee has it’s own no_results handling which will work for each nested switchee layer:

```
{if switchee_no_results}
...
{/if}
```

From http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/switchee/viewthread/2925

Comment: Please, mark your answer as right.